# glClearBuffer* clarification

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I currently use `glClearBuffer*` functions to clear draw buffers in a project running in OpenGL ES 3.0. The [glClearBuffer documentation](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glClearBuffer.xhtml) states the following:

> The **glClearBufferfv**, **glClearBufferiv**, and **glClearBufferuiv** commands should be used to clear fixed-point, signed integer, and unsigned integer color buffers respectively.

Am I right to understand it as follow:

Use `glClearBufferfv` if draw buffer is `GL_FLOAT` type
Use `glClearBufferiv` if draw buffer is `GL_INT` type
Use `glClearBufferuiv` if draw buffer is `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` type

Is that correct? I'm asking because there is no mention (from what I can tell) about the proper way to clear a draw buffer of other types, such as `GL_BYTE` and `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fv` version should be used for buffers with [normalized or floating-point image formats](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format). The `iv` and `uiv` versions should be used for buffers with signed and unsigned integer formats.

This does not restrict them to a specific format, but general *categories* of formats. `GL_RGBA8UI` is an unsigned integer format, as is `GL_R32UI`.

`GL_INT` is not any kind of image format.

Comment: I know `GL_INT` is not a format, I didn't mention it was one. But instead of having a switch case that list all known formats, wouldn't it be possible to check the **type** of the format?

Comment: @Deathicon: "*But instead of having a switch case that list all known formats*" Why would you have one? Generally speaking, you know what the formats of your render targets are. Most of the time, it's hard coded into your application. So why would you need a switch statement?

Comment: It's not hard coded, in the project users can create the content with render targets type as they need.

Comment: @Deathicon: Then the user should know what "type" they created for a render target and therefore let you know how it should be cleared when the time comes. So if they create a normalized or floating-point image, they should call the appropriate clearing function for that image. After all, the user has to provide the value to clear it to, so they have to know what kind of value to provide.

Comment: Ok I guess I can't check the **type** since that's not enough information to call the proper `glClearBuffer`, since for example `GL_R8_SNORM` is signed normalized, but `GL_R8I` is signed integral format, and both have `GL_BYTE` type, but would require `fv` and `iv` respectively.

Comment: @Deathicon: Image formats do not *have* a "type". You're talking about the [pixel transfer type](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer_Type), which has nothing to do with the image format.